# How to run python code from javascript code using xampp?

Tags: javascript, python, xampp

I have a website written in html and I have a button that when clicked should run a python script. The button is programmed in javascript, and I have seen on this site how to connect javascript and python together, but the problem is that I'm running the website using xampp and localhost, so I don't know the configurations to run the python code. I have tried to use up mod_wsgi, but the instructions are very confusing and I really have no idea what I'm doing.

I don't want to use JQuery or Ajax, I'd rather use just regular javascript to run the python code. How would I accomplish this? Basically I just want the button to run a python script I have, which is in the same directory as the website is. I don't want to run the python code from localhost directly, rather I want to reference and run it from the javascript code for the button.

Edit: it has been pointed out to me that JavaScript and python are connected through a client server relationship. Therefore my question is how to run the python code through a webserver from xampp.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking.  Can you post what you've tried?  To be sure, you do know that the python is run on the server and javascript on the client?  That means you either have to use ajax or do a traditional GET or POST to the server when the button is clicked.

Comment: I have tried using GET methods to the python file, but I don't get any errors, the code just doesn't run, meaning it doesn't make the request to the python file.

Comment: To run the python code alone I have used Flask but now I want to implement it in a website, so I downloaded xampp and apache but I'm stuck as to how exactly do I run the python code?

Comment: This is not how web development works. Java Script runs on the client, Python on the server. They are connected by request/response cycles of the website. You can not simply run Python in the browser. There have been some browser extensions that tried to make that happen, but they all lack even a basic security model and would put the whole browser at a very high risk.

Comment: @KlausD. what do you suggest as a work-around?

Comment: I think you still don't understand: You are following a completely bad approach. You can't run Python in the browser. If you need Python run it on the server (e.g. with Flask). If you need to run on the client use Java Script. That are your options.

Comment: Ok then how do I run the python code using a server like apache